# What to do with the Aluminum Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What should we do with [aluminum](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aluminum)? There is currently a tag wiki edit proposed to read

> Aluminum is one type of capacitors. This tag can also be for
>   cases/boxes, if the question is electronics related.

I don't think a tag should have two distinct meanings. Do we seperate it into two tags, or just give it one meaning?

Comment: Lets have "aluminum" for the capacitors and "aluminium" for just the metal. (j/k)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we should eliminate the aluminum tag. We have more descriptive or more accurate tags for both uses. For example, aluminum capacitors could be filed under [electrolytic-capacitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrolytic-capacitors) and aluminum cases/boxes should just be under [enclosures](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosures) or [cases](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases).

Comment: I edited it out directly. On one question where they meant aluminum-capacitor I made it just that. Otherwise I removed it.